# jquery mobile swipe does not work on image

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

Today I found this page http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/swipe/swipe-page.html that shows how HTML pages can be shifted by swiping. I did a first step to adapt this to my needs by removing the obsolete content and adding an image on the pages. Now I have the problem that the swiping does not work on the image, but only when it's done outside. How can I fix this?
My test page is http://ulrichbangert.de/orchid/newyork.html and two additional ones at the right,.
The manual pages of swipe and changePage didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using jQuery to do the code so if you add this little line of code, it will prevent images from being dragged.

```
$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

The code finds any element which is an image and once it starts being dragged, prevents the default of dragging the image away.

I ran it via console on your website and it was working so if you wanna double check it.